# Openlayers + Require.js + Backbone.js + jQueryMobile -> Tiles not loading

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, requirejs, openlayers, tiles

I have set up a project that uses require.js, backbone.js, openlayers (mobile single file build) and jquery mobile.
Now I have some issues displaying the map correctly, because no tiles are loading. I have figured out how to load the openlayers api with the require.js shim parameter:

```
shim: {
    "backbone": {
        "deps": [ "underscore", "jquery" ],
        "exports": "Backbone"
    },
    "openlayers": {
        "exports": "OpenLayers"
    }
}
```

In the MapView.js file I create a new openlayers map:

```
define([ "jquery", "backbone", "openlayers" ], function( $, Backbone, OpenLayers ) {
var MapView = Backbone.View.extend( {

    // The View Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        console.log(3);

        var mapOptions = {
                div: this.el,
                maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-174,18.4,-63.5,71),
                maxResolution: 0.25,
                projection: "EPSG:102100",
                theme: "/css/theme/default/style.css",
                layers: [
                    new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OpenStreetMap", null, {
                        transitionEffect: 'resize'
                    })
                ]};
        this.map = new OpenLayers.Map( mapOptions );
    },

    render: function() {
        console.log(4);
    }
} );
return MapView;
} );
```

Now the map works partly. I can see the Zoom Buttons which are added by openlayers at the top-left of the map, but no Tiles are loaded. Firebug told me, that there isn't even a request for the tiles.
At the moment I have no clue whats the problem might be.

For completetion this is my backbone router:

```
define([ "jquery", "backbone", "../models/Map", "../views/Map" ], function( $, Backbone, MapModel, MapView ) {

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend( {
    initialize: function() {
        console.log(2);
        this.mapView = new MapView( { el: "#mapView" } );
        Backbone.history.start();
    },

    // Backbone.js Routes
    routes: {
        "": "home",

    },

    // Home method
    home: function() {
        console.log(0);
        $.mobile.changePage( "#map" , { reverse: false, changeHash: false } );
    },
});

return Router;

} );
```

and the Page html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquerymobile.css" />
    <script src="/js/libs/require-min.js" data-main="/js/mobile"></script>
    <style>
        #mapView {
        height: 500px;
        width: 500px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map" data-role="page" data-title="Map">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Map</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="mapView"></div>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out now. All I had to do is add `this.map.zoomToMaxExtent();`. For some reason without that the map was not able to calculate the correct visible extent for the tiles.